# Symfony3 RestBundle ContextErrorExeption with OneToOne relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I needed to import big excel file, in order to keep relation to original data I had imported original excel row data to separate entity with **`OneToOne`** relation with modified data.

The importer had done great job but when I wanted to show data via RESTapi problem occurred.

very big trace with **`ContextErrorExeption`**

When I comment field that relates to original data **`OneToOne`** data is shown without exception.

Is there a reason why Symfony REST bundle do not work with OneToOne relation or I need to set up something in the config file?

I can show code, but it is a very big entity so I will show only problematic field.

```
/**
 * Contact
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="contact")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ImporterBundle\Repository\ContactRepository")
 * @Serializer\ExclusionPolicy("ALL")
 */
class Contact
{
    /**
     * @var OriginalData
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="ImporterBundle\Entity\OriginalData", inversedBy="contact")
     * @Serializer\Exclude()
     */
    private $originalData;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I found problem, I just removed **`inversedBy="contact"`**
On another side, I was just missing to add **`contact`** field.

So there was a solution to add **`contact`** filed on the joined entity or remove on the main one.

```
/**
 * Contact
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="contact")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ImporterBundle\Repository\ContactRepository")
 * @Serializer\ExclusionPolicy("ALL")
 */
class Contact
{
    /**
     * @var OriginalData
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="ImporterBundle\Entity\OriginalData")
     * @Serializer\Exclude()
     */
    private $originalData;
```